# Checking if Realm is empty?

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to use Realm to store a local database of objects. The app checks if the current session is first load and if so populates the local database with an api call. But, if the database is not empty, I would like to use the data already available. To do this, I need to know whether the database is empty or not.

I found this issue on github, but they dont provide a workaround: 
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/766

So how should this be done?

Answer (score 3):

If you scroll down that issue page, you can see [`Realm.isEmpty()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/1.0.0/api/io/realm/Realm.html#isEmpty--) is added. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Add a realm.isEmpty() method that returns true if there is no objects
>   in the Realm. It is just a utility method, but fits nicely with the
>   Realm object store abstraction.

use realm.isEmpty()

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
if(realmResults.isEmpty()) {action...}
```

or

```
if(realmResults.isNullOrEmpty()) {action...]
```

there's false but action..
What's wrong!? ...T0T